# A total well ordered set cannot be dense

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

> Let $E$ be totally ordered under $<$ , and dense. I would like to prove that a well ordered set is never dense.

To prove this, I tried to fid a non-empty subset $X$ of $E$ such that there is no least element. So, I take $X=\{z\in E: \forall x,y\in E\quad x<z<y\}$, it's non-empty because E is dense.

If I assume that there is a least element, noted $l$. We have $$\forall w\in X\quad l<w.$$ As $l\in X$ and $<$ is dense, we can find an element between $x$ and $l$, therefore $l$ is not a least element.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the argument is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott cool, Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Why is X non-empty?  If $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2$ all in E, then X has to be empty, doesn't it?  As there is no z; $x_1 < z <y_1$ and $x_2 < z < y_2$?  And as X is dense, X must be empty, mustn't it?  I might be mistaken but I don't see this.  perhaps more direct would to set $X = \{z| x<z<y\}$ for a *specific* x, y (not *all* x,y) then $X$ isn't empty and a least element $l$ leads to the same contradiction.  ... Or is that what you intended X to be all along and I just misread it?

Comment: @fleablood why there is no $z$? $<$ is dense, so whenever we take $x_1<y_1$ we can always find element between them.

Comment: Right... but you defined X so that x and y can be any elements.  they could by $x_1, y_1$  or the could be $x_2, y_2$  there is no $z$ so that $x_1 < z < y_1 < x_2 < z < x_2$.  Indeed if $y < x$ there is no $z$ at all where $x < z < y$.  I could be mistaken but I don't understand how you defined X and I think the way you defined X means X must be empty.  It's a minor point because if you defined it as "let  x < y; let X ={z|x < z < y}" your argument is just fine.

Comment: @fleablood ok I see your point,  I think you are right, thanks.

Comment: It was a minor observation.  I was a bit confused by the argument.  The argument was good but I was a little confused by what X was supposed.  I thought it might be me.  I think if you fix x and y, everything works out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As fleablood commented, this isn't quite right because your definition of $X$ isn't what you want it to be.  For $z$ to be an element of $X$, $z$ has to satisfy $x<z<y$ for *every* $x,y\in E$ simultaneously, which is impossible!  For instance, you might take $x=y=z$, in which case $x<z<y$ is definitely false.

What you want to do instead is *fix* two elements $x,y\in E$ with $x<y$ ahead of time and then define $X$ using these two fixed elements, without a quantifier.  Note that this raises an important point: the statement you are trying to prove is not actually true in general, since you need to know that two such elements $x$ and $y$ exist!  If $E$ is empty or has only one element, then in fact $E$ is both well-ordered and dense.

Comment: But for any dense set with two or more elements this is true, right? Density makes (x,y) never empty, but well ordered makes (x, min (x,y)) empty.  That *is* correct, isn't it.

Comment: Wait... so both the empty set and a singleton set are both dense and well ordered??m

Comment: Yes, the argument works as long as there are two or more elements in $E$.

Comment: Ands it's outright false for 0 and 1 elements.