# Is it correct to say that the well-ordering principle does not hold for $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, but that it does hold for $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge0}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By the well-ordering principle, every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element.

> Is it correct to say that the WOP does not hold for $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, but that it does hold for $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge0}$?

Comment: What's the least element in $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x > 1\}$?

Comment: I guess there isn't one. But this is what I've stated in question.

Comment: Under the usual ordering...

Comment: in general [WOP does not holds for dense sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907652/a-total-well-ordered-set-cannot-be-dense)

Comment: It's even worse than the examples make it seem because $1$ is rational so you could conceivably append it to the set. You could take $\{x\in\Bbb Q_{\ge 0}: 2 < x^2 \}$ for instance. The infimum is not in the set nor is it rational.

Comment: Ah.. now I see. The fact that rational set starts at $0$ doesn't mean that my subset will. Thank you all for helping me realise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not hold for $ \mathbb{Q_{\ge0}}$

For example the set of rational which are greater than $1$ does not have a minimum.